How to repair a crack/gap/hole between tarmac and concrete
I have a chip and tar driveway (tar covered in gravel) next to concrete paver path. A 1 to 2 inch gap has developed over time with erosion. I fear that a mortar repair won't adhere to the asphalt and a cold patch repair won't adhere to the concrete. It's too small a gap for retarring. What is the correct fix here?

A photo will help your case.
